# M/S - Access 2007 - Displaying Values of Parameters in a FORM

Tags: ms-access, forms, parameters

I'm just learning Access 07 and coding so, this may be a very simple question:

I have a FORM that I want to display the value of Parameters so that I know what I have inputed.  Similar to [Start Date]  & [End Date].

"Your query will start at 07/01/2009 and end on 07/10/2009."

I can do this in a REPORT "Parameters!Start Date.value" but this does not work in a FORM.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the query to throw inputboxes for your start and end dates, just make a form with start date and end date text boxes, and refer to those in your query.

So instead of:

```
Between [Start Date] and [End Date]
```

Do:

```
Between Forms!MyForm!txtStartDate and Forms!MyForm!txtEndDate
```

To put default values into the text boxes, you can use the Date function in the Form.OnLoad event.

You can say `me.txtStartDate = Date`, which will give you today's date.  You can add or subtract days from Date, and use the `DateAdd` function to add or subtract intervals such as Months.  The first day of the month is

```
CDate("1/" & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmm/yyyy"))
```

and the last day of the month is

```
CDate("1/" & Format(dat, "mmm/yyyy")) - 1
```

Comment: Robert, thanks for the quick response.  My dates will vary and I do not want to hard code the date into the query.  Actually I would like to have the parameters to be set with specific dates but be able to change them if/when I need to.  Possibly write the dates to a text file and then read in the dates into the parameters each time I start up the FORM.

Comment: I agree with Robert, I would never use popup parameter boxes - I always feed my parameters to the query from a form. This gives much greater flexibility and can be made more intuitive for the user too.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to display the paramter values on your form, echo the parameters in the SELECT statement, e.g.:

```
  PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
  SELECT MyTable.*, [Start Date] AS Starting, [End Date] AS Ending
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE MyTable.DateField Between [Start Date] And [End Date]));
```

Then as the controlsource of the control on your form that you want to display the parameters, you'd use this:

```
  ="Your query will start at " & [Starting] & " and end on " & [Ending] & "."
```

Alternatively, you could put that in the SELECT statement of your query:

```
  SELECT MyTable.*, "Your query will start at " & [Start Date] & " and end on " & [End Date] & "." AS Message
```

...and then you'd use the Message field as the controlsource of your control.